# angular 2 Highcharts Stock Chart differences

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am implementing HighCharts to display stock data, However I am not getting as many options on my chart as they do on their [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2xSewTZ9b213vA0ALmFq?p=preview), here is what I get on my application [image]

Notice the differences...

1. No option for changing time on graph
2. Date isn't piped
3. No drag bar on bottom

after comparing my code, the only difference that I can see is in the html.
In the plunker there is this line

`<chart type="StockChart" [options]="options"></chart>`

Without the `type="StockChart"` my code works with the above image output, when I add in that line I get an error. StockChart isnt an acceptable option for type.

Here is all my code

```
loadChart(){
    this.jsonp.request('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + this.values + '-c.json&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK').subscribe(res => {
            this.options = {
                title : { text : this.values + ' Stock Price' },
                series : [{
                    name : this.values,
                    data : res.json(),
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    }
                }]
            };
        });
    }
```

Worth noting: I am using angular cli, and yes I ran the npm install command for highcharts, as well as added it to my app.module. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I am using highcharts and I don't include that 'type' line

Comment: I don't either but I only get half of the graph options, see pic above

Comment: Because you use a standard chart - you should use a stockchart instead. It requires different library. Make sure you loaded the correct library and in the tag you set type to 'StockChart'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems, Turns out I had to sort my date 'Asencdingly'