# HighStock import issues with Angular 2

Tags: angular, highcharts

This question is a follow up to a previous that I had before found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769952/angular-2-highcharts-stock-chart-differences?noredirect=1#comment70799347_41769952). High charts requires two different imports for the charts itself and then the stock version of the charts. I can seem to figure out how to reference the stock portion of the import. it is a purely js import.

I have ran the npm install command for the `highstock` import and I can see it in my @types folder. I then bring in the import to my component via

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
```

However when I run my code I am still getting this error

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./ExploreComponent class ExploreComponent - inline template:4:25 caused by: StockChart is unknown chart type.
```

which is referencing my html here

```
<chart type="StockChart" [options]="options"></chart>
```

What am I doing wrong here? am I not importing 3rd party js correctly?

Comment: `StockChart` is a constructor and not a series type. You should check how is your angular2 directive (or any other responsible code) for building charts it working to find out how should the constructor be set. MAybe there is something wrong with the options that are not included in the question? A live demo in plunker would be great for tests.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this question? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Not yet, I am going to follow @KacperMadej and see if that leads me anywehre today.

Comment: I am trying to solve the same problem right now as well. Please let me know if you find anything. I will do the same for you.

Comment: @BenCameron Maybe you have a live demo for the problem? or any other way to recreate the problem?

Comment: I sure do, https://github.com/bencameron00/Ng2HighStocks

Comment: I still don't have it working but this may be of help... http://plnkr.co/edit/2xSewTZ9b213vA0ALmFq?p=preview

Comment: Has anyone had any luck yet?

Comment: @BenCameron src/index.html is not the place where Highcharts are loaded from for `angular2-highcharts`. The npm module is not an official Highsoft product, so if this is a problem with the `angular2-highcharts` (and looks like it is) then you should try to conctact it's author for help - @EugeneGluhotorenko

Comment: it seems lots of people are having this issue but he refers them to the above plnkr example. I must have something in the wrong place or missing as his example does work.

Comment: I think I have it working now. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. The solution for me was to add the below lines to my webpack.common.js file...

```
 resolve: {
      alias: {
        // NOTE: You should set 'highcharts/highcharts.src.js'
        // if you are not going to use <chart type="StockChart"
        highcharts$: "highcharts/highstock.src.js"
      },
```

I have updated my demo in GitHub with this change https://github.com/bencameron00/Ng2HighStocks

Comment: I dont have a webpack.common.js. I am just using a out of the box angular cli project

Comment: I see, maybe you should consider using webpack? It's great for minimising your app. You could just use my example from github above?